# How to Convert Rows to Columns in Mysqli Query

Tags: mysql

I want to convert Month data to columns

This Query Getting following Result

[image]

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(C.`ClientServiceDate`),'-',YEAR(C.`ClientServiceDate`)) AS 'Month',ME.`MethodName`,
       COUNT(C.`ContraceptiveMethod`) AS 'TotalUser',
       MONTH(C.ClientServiceDate) AS 'Month'
FROM mwra AS M
JOIN client_information AS C ON (C.MwraId = M.MwraId)
LEFT JOIN methods AS ME ON (ME.MethodId = C.ContraceptiveMethod)
WHERE C.FpUserStatus = 'New'
GROUP BY ME.MethodId,MONTH(C.ClientServiceDate)
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: you are probably looking for pivot tables using mysql. Plenty of ansers here already

Comment: Month Column Values to columns. just like jan_2018|feb_2018

Comment: @LelioFaieta yeah. You right but i wana dynamic colmns. Thanks

Comment: To convert rows into columns you have to perform join table with itself...

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar a while ago.

You can try with a prepared statement. Get the month names

```
SET @headers = (
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'SUM( IF(MONTH(C.`ClientServiceDate`) = ', 
             MONTH(C.`ClientServiceDate`), 
            'C.ContraceptiveMethod,0) ) AS '
            , MONTHNAME(C.`ClientServiceDate`)
            )
            ORDER BY C.`ClientServiceDate`
    )
FROM client_information  as C
);
```

And then use those headers for the prepared statement:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @headers, 'REMAINING QUERY');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: your query is good but it was getting duplicate column names just like December_2018,December_2018,January_2019.  Thanks

Comment: Just edited @header query, it was comparing MONTH with MONTHNAME.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I got another solution & I fixed that problem  Thanks again.